# Solr does not find cores when started as a Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, windows, apache, solr, nssm

On Windows Server 2012 R2:

I'd like to run Solr as a Windows Service. But if I do so (via NSSM 2.24), the service restarts every few seconds and the Solr cores are not found (the backend says: No cores available).
This is my NSSM configuration:
[image: NSSM config]
When I start Solr with the common command

```
solr start -p 8991 -m 1g
```

Solr works as expected.

I tried to modify the Path to `D:\SOLR\bc-solr5-dev\bin\solr`, but then, the service won't start.

The same behavior can be observed by using Solr 6.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was easy... I just forgot to put the `-f` flag into the NSSM configs

`start -f -p 8991 -m 1g`

NSSM needs the service to be running in foreground so that it can stop it successfully and so on.